# Calling WCF Services in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to call WCF services from ASP.NET MVC application. What is the better way to design ASP.NET MVC and WCF services communication?

1. Controller keeps the reference(s) to the WCF service(s) and calls the service methods when needed.
2. Controller Uses a DI container e.g. unity to resolve the WCF service instance. Still it is being done within the controller class.
3. Create a service mediator class that is specifically designed to communicate with a WCF service. Controller calls the mediator class(es).

Considering a reasonably complex scenario when a service is being used by multiple controllers and one controller may call mutiple services

Comment: How many palces are you making WCF calls (or re-using logic)? if it's in a single controller, just do it there. if you find yourself performing the same calls repeatedly break it out into a middle service. Keep your code "DRY".

Comment: you can add service layer in your project where you can implement all WCF service operation and implement abstract view of this layer so client classes will deal with abstract view...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller could take the ServiceContract interface you got when you generated your client side proxy as constructor parameter. And then instruct your DI framework to inject the proper instance into it (which would be the proxy implementing the service contract interface).

So basically your application has a service layer which is abstracted behind an interface (the service contract) but whose implementation lies somewhere else (in the remote WCF service).

IMHO you don't need to be creating a service mediator class unless of course your WCF service logic is not enough for your web application and you need to put even more business logic into it. In this case the mediator could help.

Comment: I agree. In most situations it will suffice to program to the service interface (contract) and inject the concrete dependency by DI framework.

Answer (score 0):

Service mediator class, additionally, can even decouple the consumer from the service totally (even interface). Service contract as well as implementation (e.g. contract method name) can be changed without impacting the client.

Answer (score 0):

Given the Service is used by multiple controllers, I think creating a service layer would be optimal.
Abstracting the WCF implementation to service layer gives the flexibility of unit testing service layer and controller actions independently.
Also keeps the controllers independent of service changes.